# Control load order?

Tags: performance

I have a full-width slider on my wp homepage. It's always last to load and everything else gets shoved around when it appears. Any way to hold the whole page from loading until it's ready, or force this element to load first??
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should test new sliders to see how fast they load. There are some which load super fast and others which aren't optimized for speed at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already put a ton of work into customising this slider so it does everything I want. I'd just like to learn how to gain more control for the way things load in wordpress - not just this slider, but in general

Comment: Try the RELATED links in the sidebar.